How to get children processes if the parent process has already exited
To make it simple, say if the python program Program_1 started process_1. Immediately after process_1 has started, process_1 starts another process process_2, and then exits itself.
Now, if Program_1 want to keep track of all processes started by process_1, but with process_1 already exited, what is a reliable way to do so?
I've tried using psutil, but the main program Program_1 can't locate process_2 if process_1 has already exited.
Calling the following when process_1 has exited will cause an psutil.NoSuchProcess as expected.
process_1.children(recursive=True)  

Other (very inefficient) approaches I've tried:

Continuously track all processes by keeping a full list of all processes (including each process and its parent's PIDs) through an additional thread. Upon the exit of the target process, check the cached list for any child processes it spawned prior to its exit.

Tracking each process individually using a dedicated thread and, as new processes are spawned, recursively initiate new threads to monitor these newly created processes.


Any idea of a more efficient approach I can take?

You can make process_1 send a list of pids of its children via a Queueq from the main process before process_1 exits:
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process

def process_1(descendant_pids):
    children = [Process(target=process_2) for _ in range(2)]
    pids = []
    for child in children:
        child.start()
        pids.append(child.pid)
    descendant_pids.put(pids)

def process_2():
    for n in range(2):
        sleep(1)
        print(current_process().pid, n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    descendant_pids = Queue()
    child = Process(target=process_1, args=(descendant_pids,))
    child.start()
    print(descendant_pids.get())

This outputs something like:
[26908, 23744]
23744 0
26908 0
23744 1
26908 1

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/AptNeglectedPoints
